# How to use CancelableOperation to cancel future chaining

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I'm not able to understand how dart async CancelableOperation.fromFuture works. It seems to cancel the first future but the .then is always executed.

While working with sockets I need to cancel a connection operation to avoid waiting for the socket timeout.

```dart
final op = f1
        .then((_) => f2);

    _connectOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(op,
        onCancel: () => throw CustomException());

    return _connectOperation.valueOrCancellation();
```

f1 gets cancelled but f2 is still executed.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is happening inside `op` would not be affected in any way. Future does not have interface for cancellation intent to be communicated towards it.

The on-success-only action can be applied to `_connectOperation`.

```
_connectOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(f1)
   .then(
      (value) => f2, // only runs if not cancelled
      onCancel: () => throw CustomException()
    );
```